# Swagger PHP and Doctrine Annotation issue

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, swagger, swagger-php

I am implementing Swagger-PHP for an API we've built.

Here is a brief recap:

**Language**: PHP5.3

**Framework**: FuelPHP 1.5.3

**Environment**: Local (served with Nginx)

Now I have an API method defined as follow:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/site/list",
 *   description="Get sites list",
 *   @SWG\Operation(...,
 *      @SWG\Parameter(...),
 *      @SWG\ResponseMessage(...),
 *      @SWG\ResponseMessage(...)
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function action_run()
{
    //doing stuff
}
```

I now try the following (from elsewhere in my application) to generate the JSON:

```
$swagger = new Swagger\Swagger('my/root/dir');
$swagger->getResource('/site/list', array('output' => 'json'));
```

And that first line here (when instanciating my Swagger class) is throwing me an error:

> ErrorException [ User Warning ]: [Semantical Error] The class
>   "package" is not annotated with @Annotation. Are you sure this class
>   can be used as annotation? If so, then you need to add @Annotation to
>   the *class* doc comment of "package". If it is indeed no annotation,
>   then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("package") to the *class* doc
>   comment of class @Swagger\Annotations\Api.

Adding the `@IgnoreAnnotation("package")` is actually not helping.

I notice the error disappears if I remove the `@package` from here:

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/library/Swagger/Annotations/Api.php#L28

But that's not a solution.

I'm guessing this is mainly Doctrine-related but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any tips or ideas on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because FuelPHP has a Package class (in fuel/core/package.php), which isn’t an @Annotation the DocParser generates this warning.

Swagger-PHP uses the $docParser->setIgnoreNotImportedAnnotations(true) setting, which should prevent warnings like these.

I've reported the issue and fixed the problem [but sadly the patch was rejected](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/25)
Report the issue (again) to doctrine, the more people complain the faster it gets fixed

As a workaround replace your DocParser.php with [this version](https://github.com/bfanger/annotations/blob/fix-doc-parser-ignore/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php)

Comment: Two years later, the original class has evolved a bit compared to this fork linked in this answer. Be careful when using his fork.

Comment: I was too optimistic, expecting my [1 line change](https://github.com/bfanger/annotations/commit/59ba7fcdb418cba9c0d19313d80a3cea40bb7aec) to be merged. I've updated the fork and re-aplied the patch.